# KitKat wireless keyboard support

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-keyboard, mouse

I have a Nexus 7 2013 Wifi running KitKat 4.4, unfortunately the glass cracked which has affected the digitiser meaning it no longer responds to touch. I have a micro USB male-USB female adapter with allows me plug in a wired keyboard and mouse via a USB hub. This allows me to use the tablet just fine, however when I plug in the receiver for my 2.4 GHZ wireless keyboard with trackpad I get no functionality.

The wireless keyboard works on my mac and pc without the need for drivers, and I would have thought this lack of need for drivers makes it a suitable candidate for working with the Nexus 7, has anyone had any success with wireless keyboards and or mice?

By wireless I mean 2.4 ghz wireless, not Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a OTG USB cable and plug in your wireless keyboard and it works like a charm. I tested this in many ways. Just like the wired keyboard and mouse, it pretty works the same.

Note: some devices may not be compatible with this method but check with your manufacturer to see if it works.

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005QX7KYU)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Must just be the manufacturer of my keyboard not being compatible as all wired devices work, just not the wireless one. Thank you.